# number of child processes

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

Is there relyable way in UNIX to know how many child processes has my certain child process? For example, main process forks child process which exec `login` program, can i know whether `login` forked or not?

**UPD** i'm using C

Answer (score 1):

Children are linked via their ppid (*parent pid*) to the parent, so it's just a matter of following those links, depending on what language you use to implement that. The `pstree` command uses this to display the process tree.

Regarding "reliable", you have to handle processes appearing and disappearing all the time, best is to snapshot the running processes as fast as possible, and only then analyze the data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go through all processes, checking their PPID (Parent Process ID) and compare that to the PID of the process you want the children of.

Comment: how can i get the list of all processes in `C`? i think, i cannot to traverse `/proc` fs, because it's not relyable - FreeBSD doesn't keep working PIDs in there like linux.

Comment: I can't find an API way to do it - maybe executing `ps` and anlyzing the output is the most portable (although ugly)

Comment: i read process' output and examine it for `Last login` string. but i want do it in more gracefull manner. localization gives a lot of headache in this way... :(

Answer (score 0):

It's crude, but you could just use a `popen` version of [what this page is doing](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_do_i_find_all_child_processes_in_unix.html), and parse the returned values.

Instead of `grep`-ing for `httpsd` you `grep` for your process.  Or you could use the `--ppid` switch on the `ps` command and just get all the child processes of this parent process.

Comment: i need to do it inside of my C program

Comment: it's not what i want. `popen` just give me ability to read process' output. i do it via pseudoterminals.

Comment: Milo, you need to put more constraints in your question; what I have said will give you a way to solve your problem (as stated) in C.

Comment: Sorry, i wanted to ask abstract question.